# How to Check Text Block Text value in Data Trigger in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to check text value of text block if value is xyz. i don not want any operation but if text value is '#FF84312F' i want to set this text to foreground color of Text.
Below is my code.
How can i achieve this . Please Help me.

```
 <TextBlock Text="#FF84312F">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="*#">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="#FF84312F">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Or this:

```
<TextBlock Text="#FF84312F">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="#FF84312F">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

It will set the `Foreground` to the value specified by the `Text` property, either unconditionally or conditionally (using a `Trigger`).

Comment: Thank you sir but Text value is not constant it can be change . May be color code will be different. i want such as contains() type thing

Comment: What are you talking about? Contains? There is no such thing in XAML. And how does this relate to your original question?

Comment: Do you have any other solution that can be help full for me .

Comment: that is not fit into my solution should i raise another question.

Comment: Of course you should ask another question if you have another issue. You may also want to consider explaining in details what you actually want when asking a question...

Comment: What i want is . I have to check textblock text and if text block text is color code then assign that color code to foreground. Tha's it

Comment: Well, then you have to write some code. You cannot do this in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:**

> This answer is based on the comments of the [answer provided by mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188602/2289942)

You can use a converter to convert your string to a `SolidColorBrush`:

**Converter class:**

```c#
public class TextToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = Brushes.Black;
        try
        {
            var converted = new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(value?.ToString());
            color = converted != null ? (SolidColorBrush) converted : Brushes.Black;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TextToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="TextToSolidColorBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="Any text">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TextToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
     </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

**based on your Comment**:

> What i want is . I have to check textblock text and if text block text
>   is color code then assign that color code to foreground. That's it

This will change the `Color` of your `Textblock` `Foreground` if `Binded` Text Value is a `Color` code else `default color` will `shown`.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Text, RelativeSource=
 {RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="#0FFFFF" Foreground="{Binding Text, RelativeSource=
{RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```